# Python/Selenium TypeError: must be str, not int

Tags: python, string, selenium, int

Alright, stuck again. I'm trying to click ahead onto the next page of LinkedIN regardless of which page I'm on. The source code shows that your current page is always `<li class="active">//whatever#</li>`... so I'm not sure why this isn't working:

```
current_page = driver.find_element_by_class_name("active")
next_page = str(current_page.text +1)
```

but when I go to click on what would be the sequential page with:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[contains(text(), "+(next_page)+"]').click()
```

I get the following error: 
"next_page = str(current_page.text +1)
TypeError: must be str, not int"

That being said, it is LinkedIN, and I have yet to be able to write a successful for loop. Everything is broken either due to a pop-up, visibility of an element, etc. I get that the platform is built to prevent it. It just seemed to me that if anything can be looped (I've had to index everything out at this point), then the list of links at the bottom could. They're visible... they're not randomized... they're everything you want to run tests with.

Just looking for some advice. Thanks SO'ers

Comment: `current_page.text +str(1)`

Comment: renders this error: "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'WebElement' and 'str'"